# problems copying shared hash in perl threads

Tags: multithreading, perl

I encountered what I feel is strange behavior of shared hash in perl and needed some help understanding it.

The actual problem is in a far larger code-base and I have tried reducing it to smaller reproducible script.

So essentially the problem I'm facing is I have a shared variable that looks something on these lines :

```
 my %headers :shared= map { lc($_) => $custom_headers->{$_} }  keys %{$custom_headers};   
 my %task1_request :shared; 
 $task1_request{count} = $count;
 $task1_request{header} = \%headers if(keys %headers);
```

i.e I end up passing a reference to a shared variable *headers* to two separate threads

Each of these threads performs "read-only" operations on the reference to hash "*headers*".

However it looks like while passing a copy of the shared hash to a function in the thread , as shown in example below :

```
iterate_header($request->{count},%{$request->{header}});

sub iterate_header
{
    my $count = shift;
    my $current_count = scalar(@_);
    if($count != $current_count) {
      print STDERR "Test failed Expected: $count, Actual : $current_count \n";
    }
    else {
      print STDERR "Test passed\n" ;
    }
}
```

results in copied hash being corrupt 
i.e The *@_* in the *iterate_header* is corrupt .

It looks to me something on the lines of the iterator being global for a shared hash as a result the copy is not thread safe. However the above is just a reckless assumption on my part and I hope someone can help clarify  as to why copying a shared hash is causing this seemingly strange behavior and if this is expected ?

**The reproducer script is  below :**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Thread::Queue;

#should run test_count * 2 times
sub iterate_header
{
    my $count = shift;
    my $current_count = scalar(@_);
    if($count != $current_count) {
      print STDERR "Test failed Expected: $count, Actual : $current_count \n";
    }
    else {
      print STDERR "Test passed\n" ;
    }
}

sub request_loop {
    my ($request_queue) = @_;

    # wait for the next reuest...
    while (defined(my $request = $request_queue->dequeue())) {
        my %result :shared;
        if(exists($request->{header})) {
            iterate_header($request->{count},%{$request->{header}});
        }
        last if(exists($request->{exit}));
        $result{is_success} = "200";
    }
}

# Main program
# create thread queues
my $task1_request_queue = Thread::Queue->new();   
my $task2_request_queue = Thread::Queue->new();    

# start worker threads
my $task1_worker = threads->create(\&request_loop, $task1_request_queue);
my $task2_worker = threads->create(\&request_loop, $task2_request_queue);

# a high number to ensure tests fail
 my $test_count = 100; 
 my $custom_headers = {
        "key" => "558193F28878E5FE",
        "username" => "Mastodon",
        "real_username" => "Mastodon",
        "type" => "EMPLOYEE",
        "expiration" => "1434556278",
        "env" => "save it",
        "for" => "some ip",
        "long-string" => "This islong string",
        "state" => "internal",
        "account" => "home",
        "original_account" => "home",
        "key" => "MCwCFAPOE74uvXso5alKytqjlfpdqeY4AhRpDeIMLCAk3ciBcyDXLdnyZjC/7Q==",
        "charset" => "iso-8859-1,*,utf-8",
        "agent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Workstation/2013.9.213.116 Safari/535.19",
        "accept" => "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "encoding" => "gzip,deflate",
        "language" => "en-us,en",
        "cookie" => "TS01375c99=012e7f4fa1e82941689f22669e2e6403ce1c75f9f8c7cb86de86c19a887f61a1109c6e2aae",
        "created" => "1434555378",

    };


my @data = %{$custom_headers};
my $count = scalar(@data);
print STDERR  "Expected Count for all tests:$count\n";
for(my $i = 0;$i < 2; $i++) {
  my %headers :shared= map { lc($_) => $custom_headers->{$_} }  keys %{$custom_headers};   
  #add to task1 q
    {    

        my %task1_request :shared; 
        $task1_request{count} = $count;

        $task1_request{header} = \%headers if(keys %headers);

        $task1_request_queue->enqueue(\%task1_request);
    }

    # add to task2 q
    {
        my %task2_request :shared; 
        $task2_request{count} = $count;

        $task2_request{header} = \%headers if(keys %headers);
        $task2_request_queue->enqueue(\%task2_request);
    }
}

my %end_request :shared = (exit => 1);
$task1_request_queue->enqueue(\%end_request);
$task2_request_queue->enqueue(\%end_request);

$task1_worker->join();
$task2_worker->join();
print "testing done\n";
```

**Example output of a test runs:**

```
[]$ perl thread_shared_issue.pl
Expected Count for all tests:36
Test passed
Test passed
Test passed
Test passed
testing done
[]$ perl thread_shared_issue.pl
Expected Count for all tests:36
Test failed Expected: 36, Actual : 16
Test failed Expected: 36, Actual : 60
Test failed Expected: 36, Actual : 18
Test failed Expected: 36, Actual : 56
testing done
```

**Perl Version Tested with**

```
perl -version

This is perl 5, version 12, subversion 5 (v5.12.5) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two threads are iterating over the same hash at the same time, so they are both changing its iterator. You need to make sure that no more than one thread uses the hash's iterator at a time.

I'd remove all those :shared and use Thread::Queue::Any.

Comment: does this mean copying a shared hash is not thread safe and it should be locked ?  intuitively copying seems to be  a read only operation  so it is odd .Is there any doc/code  where this is specified ?

Comment: Copying requires iterating over the hash, so yeah. // Documentation that the iterator is tied to the hash rather than the operator? Maybe not directly, but it can be deduced. "As a side effect, calling keys() resets the internal iterator of the HASH". And you can easily see it by using two `each` to iterate over the same hash.